# Translating polish format (.mp) file in Java

Tags: java, gis

I have `.mp` file which is related to map drawing. I know how to parse it and store the values into a `collection` in Java, but I really have no idea how to use it. I don't what '`type`', '`endLevel`', etc are used for.

Here the partial code of the file

```
[POLYGON]
Type=0x7
EndLevel=2
CityIdx=32
Data0=(-36.78826,174.62689),(-36.78843,174.62620),(-36.78763,174.62590),(-36.78746,174.62654)
[END]
```

I hope people here can make me understand how it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions for the format can be downloaded from [here](http://www.cgpsmapper.com/manual.htm).

Since this is a `POLYGON` `type=0x7` = Airport

`EndLevel=2` = Do not display below zoom level 2

`CityIdx=32` = This Airport belongs to City number 32 in the Index File.

`Data0` defines the lines that make up the shape.